# How to sign a string with a certificate's private key from the browser?

Tags: javascript, security, cryptography, certificate, digital-signature

How to sign a string with a certificate's private key from the browser ? I need to sign the string in the web, using de ceftificate instaled in the browser .

Can I use Web Cryptography API in this user case ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What kind of certificate? TLS? That's not a signing key. Most of the keys in your trusted store are not meant for signing arbitrary strings. If you insist on it, you will need access to the private key.

Comment: This is what i need.... acces to the private key or the browser do it for me and sign a data

Comment: The browser keystore is not accesible from javascript due to security restrictions. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/50208561/6371459

Comment: Thanks @pedrofb I have fount this API: WebCrypto Key Discovery: http://www.w3.org/TR/webcrypto-key-discovery/. But i think there is no implementation for this API in any browser.

Comment: No, that API does not even have a final specification

Comment: So If i want to use the client certificate instaled in the browser for indentify and authenticate my client should I use a Handshake TSL/SSL protocol?? Where the server ask to the browser for the client certificate instaled in the keystore and the client select the right certificate, but How it is works?  the browser use the private key of the client for sign something? I dont want to secure the conexion I want to indentify and authenticate  my client. Thanks a million @pedrofb

Comment: _So If i want to use the client certificate instaled in the browser for indentify and authenticate my client should I use a Handshake TSL/SSL protocol??_ -->Yes, you need to configure two ways SSL authentication. _How it is works?_ ->See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40883306/6371459). _I dont want to secure the conexion I want to indentify and authenticate my client._ -->You can authenticate the user using the SSL client certificate during login process and then grant access to your web

Comment: You may have to use any of the available Browser Extension to achieve this. Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/55757349/9659885