# How to stop HttpClient/browser from requesting Client Certificate in Blazor Wasm

Tags: c#, blazor, httpclient, webassembly, azure-api-management

When calling an API on our APIM from Blazor WASM using a HTTP client, the user is asked to select a client certificate. we don't need this extra authenticaton method since this method is secured by a jwt token.

On our APIM we have enabled the option "Negotiate client certificate" to enable some clients which can only authenticate with client certificates. Since this is enabled on the domain level it is not possible to disable this option.

Is there any way to disable the (browser) behavior through the Httpclient configuration, so the users is no longer asked to select a client certificate?

reproduction code:

```cs
@code {
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        HttpClient x = new HttpClient();
        await x.GetAsync("https://api.domain.tld/method/");
    }
}
```

I tried to set the ClientCertificateOptions to ClientCertificateOption.Manuel
I tried to set the LocalCertificateSelectionCallback, but that does need an actual certificate

I can reproduce my problem when using the js fetch api like this:

```js
fetch("https://api.domain.tld/method/", {
  method: "GET",
  headers: {
      "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key": "the-actual-key-here",
      "Authorization" : "Bearer ey...Pw"},
      "Host": "api.domain.tld",
      "Origin": "https://someorigin"
})
```

but I have no clue how to stop the browser from requesting the client certificate

Comment: You can't. This is a client-side configuration issue. Certificate selection isn't prompted by Blazor or WASM, it's done by the user's browser before the WASM code is even downloaded.

Comment: I suspect this dialog only appears in developer machines too, and you won't be able to reproduce anything on an end-user's machine. When the browser tries to establish an HTTPS connection with a server, it uses a client certificate to talk to the server. If there are multiple client certificates, the browser asks the user instead of picking one at random

Comment: There are a lot of similar questions too, like [How to stop Chrome's Select a certificate window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40653785/how-to-stop-chromes-select-a-certificate-window) and [How Chrome browser know which client certificate to prompt for a site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40847638/how-chrome-browser-know-which-client-certificate-to-prompt-for-a-site)

Answer (score 1):

You could solve this from APIM side by setting up a second custom domain name specifically for browser clients and not enabling negotiate option on it.

Comment: Thanks for the response. that does incur a big cost, we are now using the basic tier ,costing € 135/month and only the premium version costing € 2576/month has support for multiple custom domains. so this is a bit above our budget